# MBR and GPT Partition style

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, uefi, mbr, gpt

I have two storage drives in my laptop.A SSD and a HDD.I want to install windows 10 in UEFI mode on the SSD .The both disks are MBR partition style.so i'll need to convert SSD to GPT.

Do i need to convert HDD's partition style to GPT too?or it's good to go using the same MBR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have two storage drives in my laptop.A SSD and a HDD.I want to install windows 10 in UEFI mode on the SSD .The both disks are MBR partition style.so I'll need to convert SSD to GPT.
>
> Do i need to convert HDD's partition style to GPT too?

Windows cannot boot from a MBR disk while in UEFI mode.  Windows can only boot from a GPT disk while in UEFI mode, the requirement to use GPT, only applies to the system disk

> it's good to go using the same MBR?

Converting a storage device to GPT is not required in the case you describe.